# Null, primitive data value and wrapper class in method call

Tags: java, methods, null, type-conversion, primitive-types

I have following code snippet

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      test(1);//fine & output - int
      test(1L);//fine & output - long
      //test(null);  fine & output - Integer
      test(12233333333);//error
    }

    static void test(int a){
        System.out.println("int");
    }
    static void test(Integer a){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
    static void test(long a){
        System.out.println("long");
    }
    static void test(Long a){
        System.out.println("Long");
    }
    static void test(List<Integer> a){
        System.out.println("List");
    }
}
```

My question is,

Why number value always refer int(primitive type) but null refer the most specific method among the overloads?

Why we need to say implicitly 1L why it not taking long value if u give big number(1233333333333)?
 Can u some one explain those?

Comment: `test(null)` for me gives a compilation error saying that the method is ambiguous.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Hi, while test(null) please use first two method

Comment: Although the linked duplicate is closed, it will answer your question.  In short:  the standard has specified the default type of numerals to be `int`, and `int`'s max value is only 2^(32-1)-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why number value always refer int(primitive type) but null refer the
>   most specific method among the overloads?

Because by default compiler refers to the 32-bit integer operation for number without suffix `l` OR `L` *(for `long`)*.

> Why we need to say implicitly 1L why it not taking `long` value if u
>   give big number(1233333333333)? Can u some one explain those?

As I said above it by default refers to the integer operation and for such a big number it is out of the range of the `Integer` as this number will be considered as integer without suffix `l` or `L` so it will refer to the method which takes `int` as parameter but error comes up that value is out of range.

<sub>Let's see what JLS says..</sub>

> [`JLS 4.2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)
>   If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one
>   operand of type long, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit
>   precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type long.
>   If the other operand is not long, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type
>   long by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and
>   the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand
>   is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.

Answer (score 0):

1233333333333 is an int literal so you could use that but you would have to cast it to long in which case the compiler will do the conversion. It does not work because it is too large to be an int.

The reason the compiler cannot just assume it is long is because ithey would be inconsistent with 123 being an int.

Comment: 1 *trillion* is not an `int` literal.  A `long` literal, maybe - but it'd need to be expressed as `1233333333333L`.

Comment: That is exactly the point read the question he is asking why isnt it an int and the second sentence in my answer.

Comment: I was remarking to the fact that you state that 1233333333333 is an int literal, when it simply *isn't*.

Comment: Because it is too long?  That is what i say in my second sentence.

Comment: It may be that you're misunderstanding [what a literal is.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) Since this number exceeds the max `int` value, Java will not compile unless you append `L` or `l` to the end of it.  At that point, it is no longer an `int` literal, it is a `long` literal.  That's the point I'm making here.

Comment: As the JLS states (under 3.10.1, "integer literals") "It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary `int` literal does not fit in 32 bits.". So `int` literals that do not fit in 32 bits do exist, but they are invalid; they trigger a compile-time error. I guess that's the point that @redge was trying to make, the problem is that it is an (invalid) `int` literal when it should have been a `long` literal.